# How to set additional classpath for the driver and executors when launching spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark

The documentation on how to configure and run spark-shell - and probably similarly for spark-submit - is not completely clear.

Here is what I have tried:

```
spark-shell --master <master IP:port> --executor-memory 8gb \ 
--total-executor-cores 10 --driver-memory 8gb \
--driver-class-path /opt/cloudera/CDH/lib/hive/lib \
--driver-java-options "-Dspark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/cloudera/CDH/lib/hive/lib"
```

This does not work: the program does not launch. Actually it returns immediately.

The items that I am most in need of clarification are the --driver-class-path and driver-java-options on how to set the spark.executor.extraClassPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not where I expected it: the issue is the

```
--driver-memory 8GB
```

. That does not work. Removing it and the other settings are fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's my solution for Windows 7 (long line to show 3 different paths)

```
spark-shell --master local --driver-class-path ..\..\path1\jar1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\path2\jar2.jar;target/playground-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

So 3 things to make it work:

1. Use **--driver-class-path** option
2. Separate jars with *;* char
3. Do not enclose paths with *"* chars